# Reference to object passed to function Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

To understand more about Python's objects and classes I wrote some code for a Binary Search Tree.

For the delete method when I try to change what the node is pointing to, python is creating a new variable instead of altering the node that is passed to the method. How would I be able to change what node is pointing to inside the method?

```
class Node:

def __init__(self):
    self.data = None
    self.left = None
    self.right = None


class BST:

def __init__(self):
    self.root = None
    self.length = 0

def insert(self, data):

    if not self.root:
        temp = Node()
        temp.data = data
        self.root = temp
    else:
        return self._insert(self.root, data)

def _insert(self, node, data):

    if node.data <= data:
        if not node.right:
            temp = Node()
            temp.data = data
            node.right = temp
            return
        else:
            self._insert(node.right, data)
    else:
        if not node.left:
            temp = Node()
            temp.data = data
            node.left = temp
            return
        else:
            self._insert(node.left, data)

def delete(self, data):

    return self._delete(self.root, data)

def _delete(self, node, data):

    if not node:
        return False
    elif node.data < data:
        return self._delete(node.right, data)
    elif node.data > data:
        return self._delete(node.left, data)
    else:
        if not node.left and not node.right:
            node = None
        elif not node.left:
            node = node.right
        elif not node.right:
            node = node.right
        else:
            temp = self.findmin(node.right)
            #or find max of left
            node.data = temp.data
            self._delete(node.right, temp.data)

def findmin(self, node):
    if not node:
        return None
    while node.left:
        node = node.left
    return node
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the python issue, this would be the same for every single language using pointers (and not c++ style references). During delete operation you should change pointer of the **parent's** node reference to its children. You have a structure of the form

```
       parent
       /   \
     node  ...
     /  \
child1  child2
```

when removing `node` you have to change **parent** children to new ones, not try to assign new value to a "node" variable, which is not pointing anywhere. Thus you will end up with something like:

```
       parent
       /    \
     child1  ...
     /  \
child2  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My first if statement in the _delete method checks if there are no children and then points node to None but it is creating a new variable node instead of referencing to self.root that is passed from the delete method.

Comment: again - this is not a reference in the c++ sense. Think about it as a pointer. You cannot "assign new pointer to the same variable". You cannot remove a "root". You need a main object, tree object, which will always show "where" is the root. And if you remove the root - you have to change this reference, nothing else.